# Software updater msg: "Failed to download repository information" Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: apt

When I run software updater, I get the message:

```
Failed to download repository information
```

But when press OK, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and find out what is going on there by executing:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Most probably you'll find out something like this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://...
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Then open **Software & Updates** app, go to **Other Software** tab and disable faulty repository.

Then close and open it again to be sure this error message disappears.